# How to store python results in Django model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I wrote one .py file which will do some network functions and save the one value

I should save this value in Django model that is in database

I wrote a .py file in the main project when I run python some.py I will get one result that should be in a database I am using the Django framework

Comment: So is the python file inside a django app?

Comment: yes  python file inside a django app

Comment: So what is your question? Where are you having trouble? Why would saving the results of this script be any different from saving any other value?

Comment: actually, i need the access  token to be stored in my database and use that access token for future.

Comment: So when do you want this script to be run?

Comment: when I click a button on jsx page this code will run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your code in your view of the django app. When you clicked a button, client will send a kind of http request to server, right?And then you can do some operation on your database when dealing with the request. Most important, you should first define your database table in your app model and do migration operation before start the project.